# How do I use/import JavaScript file correctly in React project correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I am trying to add/import js file in my React project, in a functional component to be exact. I know that there are some answers for this question (sort of this question) out there on stackoverflow but I am not able to use any of the solution or may be I just didn't find correct one yet. What I am trying to do is that I have a js file which I want to keep in src folder and not public if possible. So the `myAnimation.js` file is in `src/assets/js/` folder. Now how can I import and run this file in my React project's functional component?

Basically I want to add this animation in my app : https://codepen.io/jasperlachance/pen/QNMwBg

So there are three js file in the codepen which I want to download and save it in my project instead of using the CDN links that this codepen has. So what would be best approach to have the three js files downloaded in my project and run it on a specific component lets say `MyComponent` which I import on route `MyRoute`. Also, I am using TypeScript. So how can I import js files and make them run one after another once the component is loaded/mounted and it has mounted/created html elements?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: React IS javascript

Comment: Does my updated question makes sense @k-wasilewski ?

Comment: That is a cool effect - you could try including them as references:

<https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element>

Comment: This might help too: <https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html>

Comment: @ColemanTO this still requires to put js file somewhere publicly accessible like in public folder.

Comment: Yes, it would - are you looking to obfuscate it?

Comment: @ColemanTO I went ahead and added js files in public folder. Thanks for your help. :D

Comment: You're welcome - glad to help.